# In exact section show div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I'm creating template website and there's an idea.
When I scroll to section `#offer` - div named `call-button` show up. When I scroll out of this section div dissapears. I was using this code, but it's not really what I want. **It shows call button only on bottom of div.** And I want it to show on whole section, dissapear if not in section #offer.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(
      '#offer').offset().top + $('#offer').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {

    $('.call-button').fadeIn();

  } else {
    $('.call-button').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<section id="offer">
  <div class="call-button">
    <a href="tel:+48111222333">791000394</a>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve. "It shows call button only on bottom of div" which div? It appears where you put it in the html. Are you not happy at what point it appears?

Comment: Hey! I want to show `call-button` div - when I'm scrolling through section `#offer`. When I scroll out of section I want it (`call-button) to fade out. Code below bolded text is what I've now.

Comment: Specify scrolling through section.. If you scroll out of the section what's the point of fading it out? As it's not visible anyway..

Comment: Do you mean you want the call button to be sticky(always visible no matter how much scrolling) but only inside the offer section?

Comment: I've very big in height offer section (https://i.imgur.com/efp4V55.png). Button has position fixed. I just want to make him dissapear outside of section 'offer'.

Comment: yeah, just what I thought. We call them 'sticky' elements

Comment: change it from `position:fixed` to `position:sticky`

Comment: But what's the point of using `position: sticky`? I've checked it just now and I don't understand how it could do the job I've described before :P https://i.imgur.com/IXCcJEC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in **pure javascript**:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let sec = document.querySelector('#offer');
  let btn = sec.querySelector('.call-button');

  let secTopDis = sec.offsetTop;
  let secBottomDis = secTopDis + sec.offsetHeight;

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= secTopDis && window.pageYOffset <= secBottomDis)
      btn.classList.add('visible');
    else
      btn.classList.remove('visible');
  });
});
```

Basically, you've to add opacity or whatever you want to do it. And set it to `0`.

```css
.call-button {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  /* STYLE */
}
```

And add class visible which has `opacity: 1`.

```css
.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Script basically when in section/div is adding class `.visible`.
There I'm leaving you code on which I was working. Have fun.

```js
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let sec = document.querySelector('.b');
        let btn = sec.querySelector('a');
        
        let secTopDis = sec.offsetTop;
        let secBottomDis = secTopDis + sec.offsetHeight;

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if(window.pageYOffset >= secTopDis && window.pageYOffset <= secBottomDis)
                btn.classList.add('visible');
            else
                btn.classList.remove('visible');
        });
    });
```

```css
        *
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div
        {
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .a
        {
            background: red;
        }
        .b
        {
            background: blue;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .c
        {
            background: yellow;
            height: 150vh;
        }
        a
        {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            color: #1a1a1a;
            background: #f2f2f2;
            border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 30px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 1s ease-out;
        }
        .visible
        {
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="a">

    </div>
    <div class="b">
        <a href="#">POOF POOF</a>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        
    </div>
```